# group by subquery in sql server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery

I have a table and want to group the records by dynamically generated column. Say as in my query it is newcol. On executing this query i am receiving the error:

> Column 'SalesProductDetails.ProductId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is query i have tried

```
select tbl.nwecol,tbl.ProductId,tbl.Products_Name,tbl.Qunatity,tbl.SKUCode
from (
    select SPD.ProductID,
        PR.SKUCode,
        PR.Products_Name,
        sum(SPD.Qunatity) as Qunatity, 
        cast(round(((SPD.BasePrice*SPD.Qunatity)+STD.SalesTaxAmt)/SPD.Qunatity,2) as numeric(36,2)) as nwecol,
        SM.Isactive
    from SalesProductDetails SPD
    join SalesMaster SM
        on SPD.SalesId=SM.SalesId
    join Sales_TaxDetails STD
        on SPD.ProductSalesID=STD.ProductSalesID
    join Products Pr
        on Pr.ProductID=SPD.ProductId
    where SPD.Isactive=1
        and SM.Isactive=1
        and SPD.ProductId=1
) as tbl
group by tbl.nwecol,tbl.ProductId,tbl.Products_Name,tbl.Qunatity,tbl.SKUCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to do is calculate the sum based on the column you generated (nwecol). In that case, you need to move the aggregate (SUM) outside of the subquery like so:

```
select tbl.nwecol,tbl.ProductId,tbl.Products_Name,tbl.SKUCode,
    SUM(tbl.Qunatity)
from (
    select SPD.ProductID,
        PR.SKUCode,
        PR.Products_Name,
        SPD.Qunatity
        cast(round(((SPD.BasePrice*SPD.Qunatity)+STD.SalesTaxAmt)/SPD.Qunatity,2) as numeric(36,2)) as nwecol,
        SM.Isactive
    from SalesProductDetails SPD
    join SalesMaster SM
        on SPD.SalesId=SM.SalesId
    join Sales_TaxDetails STD
        on SPD.ProductSalesID=STD.ProductSalesID
    join Products Pr
        on Pr.ProductID=SPD.ProductId
    where SPD.Isactive=1
        and SM.Isactive=1
        and SPD.ProductId=1
) as tbl
group by tbl.nwecol,tbl.ProductId,tbl.Products_Name,tbl.SKUCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is unclear about the error message.  Your aggregation is on the following columns:

- tbl.nwecol
- tbl.ProductId
- tbl.Products_Name
- tbl.Qunatity
- tbl.SKUCode

None of these are `tbl.ProductId`.  So, you can solve this by wrapping the latter in an aggregation function, such as:

```
MIN(tbl.ProductId)
MAX(tbl.ProductId)
```

Or, include `tbl.ProductId` in the `group by`.

Comment: i want sum of the quantity and group by newcol. I dont think their is requirement to apply min or max on productid instead i can just mention productid without min or max.  

can u give me an example..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is need not to use group by clause without using any aggregate function like (sum,avg,count,max) . Let's try without group by clause in outer select statement

Answer (score 0):

you have used product_id for Product_details As PR table in the join but missed to write the same in the group by clause!!!!